# Creating a TFDQuery Dynamically disappears

Tags: delphi

I are using Delphi Berlin 10.1

When I create a TFDQuery it dont seem to be able to access it in my code using Findcomponent.

creation

```
procedure TDataModule1.QuVerConAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  QuVerCon.First;
  while not QuVerCon.Eof do
  begin
    if QuVerCon.FieldByName('Table').AsString <> 'versioncontrol' then
    begin
      TFDQuery.Create(self).Name := 'Qu' + QuVerCon.FieldByName('Table').AsString;
      with TFDQuery(FindComponent('Qu' + QuVerCon.FieldByName('Table').AsString)) do
      begin
        Connection := SqlConn;
        Open('select * From ' + QuVerCon.FieldByName('Table').AsString);
      end;
    end;
    QuVerCon.Next;
  end;
  FMMain.Filter1.FormatScrn(FMMain.Filter1);
end;
```

Disconnection

```
procedure TDataModule1.SqlConnBeforeDisconnect(Sender: TObject);
var
  Tbl: TFDQuery;
begin
  with QuVerCon do
  begin
    First;
    if FieldByName('Table').AsString <> 'versioncontrol' then
    begin
      Tbl := TFDQuery(FindComponent('Qu' + FieldByName('Table').AsString));
      if Assigned(Tbl) then
        TFDQuery(FindComponent('Qu' + FieldByName('Table').AsString)).Free;
    end;
    Next;
  end;

  QuVerCon.Close;
end;
```

The code skips over "if Assigned(Tbl) then" as it cant find it
where are I going wrong?

Is the a way to show a message box with a list of components of the data module so I can check when is disappears?

Comment: Why are you jumping through so many hoops? Create a `TDictionary<string, TFDQuery>`, add your query there (giving it a meaningful name as the `string` key), and you can easily retrieve the value from the dictionary any time you need it. (And even if you don't, your Free loop is nonsense. You find the query and assign it to `Tbl`, and then don't use `Tbl.Free` but look it up again in order to free it. What's the point of that?)

Comment: There's a possibility that **with** results in your code behaving differently to what you expect. Which `FindComponent` do you want to call? I strongly recommend you break the habit of relying on the terrible **with** construct.